# BasicAuthenticationFilter onUnsuccessfulAuthentication call twice

Tags: spring, spring-boot

in beans:

```
<http auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/server/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/includes/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/help/**/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <custom-filter ref="unsuccessfulBasicAuthenticationFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    </http>
```

Call twice:

```
public class UnsuccessfulBasicAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

 @Override
    protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException {
        if (failed instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            failedLogonAttemptsHandler.onFailedLogonAttempt();
        }
        super.onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }
}
```

But method `onUnsuccessfulAuthentication` call twice.

Comment: Can you try to log URL in both invocations ? I suspect first invocation is for the request itself, second is for /error redirection.

Comment: @Gaurav Both urls are same:  http://some_ip:8091/ws/cpeService12

Comment: Is it possible`super.onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed)`  call the `failedLogonAttemptsHandler.onFailedLogonAttempt()` again ?

Comment: @Gaurav I remove super.xxx but same result. Request call twice

Comment: Okay. I am beat. :)
Can you create a repo so that I can take a look ?